# Reshape Images from ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

With image data generator's flow_from_directory method can we reshape images also.

e.g. we have color images in 10 classes in 10 folders and we are providing path of that directory let's say train:

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, width_shift_range=0.05, height_shift_range=0.05)

train_imgs= gen .flow_from_directory(
        '/content/data/train',
        target_size=(10,10),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

Now my model is taking input shape 300. And I want to define training data from this train_imgs that is images of 10X10X3.

Is there any library, method or option available to convert this data generator to matrix in which columns are each image vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best option in these cases is to add a Reshape layer to the start of your model: `layers.Reshape((300), input_shape=(10,10,3))`. You can also do `layers.Reshape((-1), input_shape=(10,10,3))`, and it will automatically figure out the correct output length.

Comment: that is giving error but layers.Reshape((-1,-1) , input_shape=(10,10,3)) is working that is first argument needs 2 int in tuple , Thanks for Help

Comment: BTW it is (None,1,300) shape; is there any way to get it in (None,300).

Comment: If the solution he provided didn't work for you, please don't mark it as accepted.